# Optimizing MySQL hundreds of records combined into a hundred groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with hundreds of records (certainly it's not a huge database but I'd like to keep it that way). I want to let users create as many groups from the records as they wish (put any of the records into any of these groups). My idea was to use a binary number at each row, where bits would indicate whether the record is part of the corresponding (power of 2) group or not.
Say there are 8 groups, therefore 8 bits:

```
banana | ... | 00010011 // banana is in group 0,1 and 4
orange | ... | 00010000 // orange is in group 4 only
flower | ... | 11111111 // flower is member of every group
```

This is very tiny and convenient, easy to handle in the WHERE clause - however,  this cannot go on forever, e.g. to change the bits I'm using PHP's bindec()/decbin() functions which have limits in the maximum number of characters.
I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Well lets say there are 100000 groups, That binary idea will not work will it

Comment: Do it properly and create a cross reference table for each user to their groups and another for this users items in a group

Comment: A properly indexed cross-reference table will be a lot more efficient for selects

Comment: a pivote table with group id and member and your member table is simple and straightforward method..

Comment: Thanks for all. I'm gonna check that pivoting stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a matrix of records and groups, a meta table.

One table with your records (1:banana, 2:orange, 3:flower etc.)
One table with the user created groups (100:group1, 200:groupfruits, 300:groupplants, 400:groupwhatever).

One table that holds the connections between group and records:

```
group_id | record_id
100      | 1
100      | 3
200      | 1
200      | 2
300      | 3
400      | 1
400      | 2
400      | 3
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about sg like that but I was also wondering whether creating a table with tens of thousands of rows (a hundred groups with a few hundred records each) is the way to go. I'm a completely beginner when it comes to execution time etc. so it may not be an issue at all.

Comment: Thousands of rows shouldn't be a problem if you index the table properly and use proper joins. I am using such meta/pivot tables with millions of entries without any issues.